# Retrieve distinct values without reducing number of results

Tags: mysql, limit, distinct

I'm writing a MySQL request for retrieving data from a list of questions.
The table looks like this :

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| id | answer_name | rating | question_id | answers |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Where several rows can have the same `answer_name` value, since several questions can be asked about the same answer.

Now, for retrieving the data I use a LIMIT clause which is calculated from ratings and the total number of rows.
For example, if I wanna get the data between 80% and 100% of rating, and there are 100 rows, I would use ORDER BY rating LIMIT 80, 20.

My problem is the following : I need to retrieve data with distinct values for `answer_name` column, but using a GROUP BY clause makes the number of result (e.g. of rows in the table) reduce cause of aggregation, causing the top percentages of rows to return nothing cause of searching rows at a limit that doesn't exist.

Does anyone know if there is a way to keep the number of results the same and still to retrieve distinct results for the `answer_name` column ?

**EDIT :**

Here are some sample rows and expected output :

`game_data` table :

```
 -----------------------------------------------------
 | id | answer_name | rating | question_id | answers |
 |----|-------------|--------|-------------|---------|
 |  1 | A. Merkel   |  40    |  1          | [1,2,3] |
 |  2 | A. Merkel   |  45    |  2          | [2,3,4] |
 |  3 | B. Clinton  |  55    |  1          | [2,5,8] |
 |  4 | B. Clinton  |  50    |  2          | [3,5,8] |
 |  5 | L. Messi    |  17    |  4          | [7,8,9] |
 |  6 | L. Messi    |  18    |  5          | [7,8,9] |
 |  7 | L. Messi    |  25    |  6          | [7,8,9] |
 |  8 | D. Beckham  |  21    |  4          | [6,7,8] |
 |  9 | D. Beckham  |  52    |  5          | [6,7,8] |
 | 10 | D. Beckham  |  41    |  6          | [6,7,8] |
 -----------------------------------------------------
```

Where answers is an array of ids referring to another table.

Let's say I wanna retrieve the 50% to 80% of the table, ordered by rating.

```
SELECT id FROM game_data GROUP BY answer_name ORDER BY rating LIMIT 5, 3
```

Here the problem is the GROUP BY answer_name is gonna reduce the number of rows of the table, and therefore instead of returning 3 results, will return an empty set.

Also, I want the selected value in the GROUP BY close to be randomly chosen.

Comment: In your question include some existing rows and expected output sample.

Comment: if the same answer has different ratings, and belongs to a different question, which of the different values do you want to use?

Comment: @RavinderReddy I posted a sample.

Comment: @pala_ I'd like it to be randomly selected

Comment: "Where answers is an array of ids referring to another table." That is a great shame.

Answer (score 0):

Using `group by` like this goes against pretty much every instinct, but you said you want random values, so it's good enough.

```
select * from (
  select q.*, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank 
    from (
      select * from game_data
        group by answer_name
        order by rating desc
    ) q, (select @rank := 0) qq
  ) qqq
  where rank between (@rank * .5) and (@rank * .8)
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/167860/5)

How does it work?  First (in the innermost query) we group by your answer_name, to get your distinct results, and we order it by the rating as required.

Then in the query wrapping around that one, we give those results a ranking from 1 to however many rows are in the result.  Once this level of the query completes, we know our best answer is answer `1`, and our 'worst' answer is the last value of our `@rank` variable.

Then we get to the outermost query. We can use that @rank variable to determine our percentages, which we use to filter the `where` clause.

In all likelihood this will give you the same results each time you run the same query, but the values chosen are indeterminate - so it could change. If you want truly random (ie changes with each execution) that's a different kettle of fish altogether.

(note, this bit: `, (select @rank := 0) qq` is purely to initialise the variable)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not return the appropriate questions with the given order of rating here

Comment: @Littletime You said you wanted it randomly in the comment when i specifically asked you which rating from the group of names. Are you saying now you want the data from the highest ranked answer per person?A

Comment: Yeap, randomly chosen from the aggregation. Sorry for expressing badly

Comment: After thinking a little more I think this problem is a no go from the expressed point of view, and I think I might have found something out. If it works I'll post it here

Comment: @Littletime I am still not sure what you want. For each answer_name, group them together, get their max rating, AND the question_id and answer that goes WITH that max rating?

Comment: Well, i'd like to get all the questions for a certain range, and then order them randomly and select just a few ones, and in those few ones, i don't want the answer_name to be duplicate

Comment: Even though some questions can have ids next to each other and have the same answer_name. I have enough data to make the unicity possible

Comment: @Littletime is [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/167860/17) any closer to what you want? maybe this data set is too little since by definition the most rows you can have returned is 4. If you were to want the top 3 answers, would you get one from merkel, beckham and clinton?

Answer (score 0):

Simple is That.

Use Group By 'id' not 'answer_name' b/c Group By not get duplicate values

```
SELECT * FROM game_data GROUP BY id ORDER BY rating
```